# Polymer: open modal with dynamic id

Tags: javascript, polymer

```
<dom-module id="profile-post">
--------------------------
<template>
    <paper-button onclick="friends[[post_id]].open()">Invite here</paper-button>
    <paper-dialog id="friends[[post_id]]" entry-animation="scale-up-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation" with-backdrop>
</template>
<dom-module>
```

Other file in my app calls profile-post

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{ajaxResponse.objects}}" as="post">
    <div class="wall">
        <div id="new_post_here"></div>
        <profile-post
            photos      = "{{ post.photos }}"
            date        = "{{ post.date }}"
            message     = "{{ post.message }}"
            place_name  = "{{ post.place_name }}"
            post_id     = "{{ post.id }}"
            class       = "post">
        </profile-post>
    </div>
</template>
```

All values in square brackets are attributes for my own-element. Own-element has simple template, but from another part of my app i call this element inside dom-repeat. Paper-dialog doesn't open.

I solve this problem in such way:

```
             <paper-button id="bp[[post_id]]" onclick="friends[[post_id]].open()">Invite here</paper-button>
             <paper-dialog id="friends[[post_id]]" entry-animation="scale-up-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation" with-backdrop>

    openMap: function (e) {
        console.log('openMap');
        if(e.target.id == ('bm'+this.post_id)){
            document.getElementById('map'+this.post_id).open();
        }else if(e.target.id == ('bp'+this.post_id)){
            document.getElementById('friends'+this.post_id).open();
        }
    }
```

But it's not beautiful

Comment: Please include any errors/stack traces you see in the browsers console, so we can get an idea of what is happening.

Comment: i've updated post

Comment: In order to give dynamic value to `attributes` like `id` you have to use `$`. It will be `id$=`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it this way:

```
<paper-button id="bp[[post_id]]" on-tap="_openDialog">Invite here</paper-button>
<paper-dialog id="friends[[post_id]]" entry-animation="scale-up-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation" with-backdrop>


_openDialog: function(e) {
    this.$$('#friends'+e.target.id').open();
}
```